# Is there a group called 'meaningless sentences'?

Tags: grammar, expressions, semantics

Some sentences, like *I am dead, I am lying, I am sleeping* etc. do not convey a meaning. Is there a grammatical class or any other grouping for such expressions?

Comment: I am dead when my father finds out.  Look at this picture. I am sleeping.  I am lying because I don't want to hurt her feelings.  What do you mean they don't convey any meaning?  They all mean what they say.

Comment: I am sleeping.  Will you please go away and leave me in peace!!

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples do convey meaning. I would be hard put to think of any sentence, out of context, that conveys nothing. When and if, however, you do find such a sentence, it is called a

> semantic blank

or, usually with reference to words, phrases, or sounds, rather than complete sentences,

> semantic filler, filler word, pause filler, hesitation form, etc.

Of the latter, they range from the common "uh, oh, I mean, let's see now" through exotics such as "arg" and "howse"

(See ["filler word"](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/fillerterm.htm) at [*about education*](http://www.about.com/education/).)

Usually, however, when you encounter a semantic blank, it's *blank* not because it conveys no meaning, but because it conveys relatively little (not no) meaning *in a specific context*.

Generally, the term 'semantic blank' is used for such "filler" sentences as are offered merely out of politeness, or as a formulaic greeting, and aren't intended to elicit a reply to their meaning, but rather to the social form. A common one is

> How are you?

This is only a semantic blank because it's not intended to elicit a detailed reply to the question, but only a formulaic one:

> I'm fine. [But really, all my relatives are sick and dying, the dog ran away and the cat won't speak to me, I feel ill, a hurricane has demolished the property I was counting on as an investment for my retirement....]

So, in the examples, "How are you?" and "I'm fine." might be called semantic blanks, but notice that they do convey a ritual social meaning which, although it doesn't correspond to the literal meaning of the sentence, is nonetheless meaningful.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I find it hard to accept that "how are you?" really is a semantic blank. Most of the people I know ask and respond to this question sincerely, and we give sincere detailed answers to such a question, nowhere near as a ritual.

Comment: @user21820, It is a matter of context. The circumstances where "how are you?" is nothing more than a formula, for me, are when greeting strangers and acquaintances, at work or elsewhere; there, if somebody asks and you reply with anything other than the formulaic response, you soon discover that your reply is unwanted and indeed inappropriate. Only the formulaic response will do.

Comment: Oh if you meant with unfamiliar people then yea agreed. Perhaps you should clarify that?

Comment: @user21820, Why do you think it's unclear?

Comment: As you said, it is a matter of context, and in my opinion is not semantically empty when used with close family or friends. I interpreted your phrasing in your answer to mean that it is always a semantic blank, which you don't seem to mean in your comment.

Comment: @user21820, It's interesting that you should think the expression was unclear, rather than that your interpretation was slovenly: "in a specific context" is *emphasized* in the answer; "filler sentences ... offered merely out of politeness, or as a formulaic greeting, [not] intended to elicit a reply to their meaning, but rather to the social form" spells out the circumstances, in no uncertain terms, when the examples are semantic blanks.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and it never occurred to me that you meant to restrict "How are you?" to specific contexts. This is how I interpreted your phrasing: `"How are you?" is a 'filler' sentence, which is offered merely out of politeness, or as a formulaic greeting, and isn't intended to elicit a reply to their meaning, but rather to the social form.` Now I know that you mean `"How are you?", when offered merely out of politeness, or as a formulaic greeting, and isn't intended to elicit a reply to their meaning, but rather to the social form, is a 'filler' sentence.`, but it wasn't clear.

Comment: @user21820, this is getting more than a little ridiculous, but I didn't mean either thing you've contrived in your last comment. You are, of course, free to misinterpret however you please without my collaboration.

Comment: If you didn't mean either, then I really don't know what your answer is supposed to mean.